# Need help with a definite integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2^x-1}\ln(2^x-1)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2^x-1}\ln(2^x-1)}\,dx$$

---

I am not sure where to start or what should be the best approach towards this problem. I tried the substitution $2^x-1=t^2$ but that seems to make things more worse. Using this substitution, I got:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln^2 2}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2}\right)}{(1+t^2)\ln t}\,dt$$
I don't see how to proceed after this. :(

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried $t=\tan\theta$ ?

Comment: Ah, how could I not see it, thanks a lot Awesome! :)

Comment: Thanks but those approaches are a little complicated. I like Awesome's approach and Awesome's method is quite a standard trick, I have been using it all the time but this time, I missed it.

Comment: @PranavArora Just sub $t\mapsto \dfrac{1}{t}$ to regenerate the integral and get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $t=\tan\theta$

Simplify everything in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Substitute $\pi/2-\theta=\phi$ and add and do what you do with other definite questions. Be sure to completely simplify your numerator to break into two integrals.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by break into two integrals but I got the answer though.

Comment: @PranavArora It is irrelevant now.